# Using variable as stdClass property name

Tags: javascript, php, json

### The goal

Using `$context` as property name of a `stdClass` in `PHP`.

### The Scenario

There is  the following scenario in my application:

```
[...]

public function diagnose($issue, $index)
{
    $json = json_decode($this->getJson());
    $json->$issue[$index]
}

[...]
```

The instance:

```
$investigator = new Investigator;
$investigator->diganose('parameters', 0);
```

The JSON:

```
{
    "parameters": [
        "There is missing a parameter."
    ]
}
```

### The error

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$p in
>   [...] on line 25

So, I want to access `parameters` of my JSON's object with flexibility. How can I perform this?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
public function diagnose($issue, $index)
{
    $json = json_decode($this->getJson());
    $data = $json->$issue;

    return $data[$index];
}
```